# Going Through Users in Database Individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, iteration

I have been searching and searching for help on this question, but I have found no luck. I am wanting to have a page that displays each user in my database one at a time, and when I press a 'Next' button, it will go to the next user in the database and display their information. I have been seeing this code everywhere:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li>
     # Add some code
</li>
<% end %>
```

but this is displaying every user all at once on my page. I would like to only display a single user at a time. If anyone could direct me to a good source or has a simple explanation, I would be forever grateful!

Comment: paginate your users. per page show only a single user. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem. You will be able to `paginate` your results one by one (one result per page, hence the name).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to paginate the `@users` records. I prefer using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem.

After including it in your gem file, you may use it like:

```
@users = User.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 1)
```

For basic understanding, the gem basically uses **limit** and **offset** in SQL query to attain the record. If you don't want to use the gem, then you may try like:

```
User.limit(1).offset(params[:offset].present? ? params[:offset] : 0)
```

And on clicking on **next** you may pass the incremented value of offset each time as parameter.